# Creating and Implementing a Database for iOS Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, database, ios4, sdk

Brief:     Ok. I'm looking to implement and create a database with several tables to put in a iOS app. I know SQLite is an option but can you put SQLite online so data stays current on each device? I haven't made a SQLite database but I've done a MySQL through PHP.

Question: What route should I use? I've just heard of SQLite and don't want to waste time. Please in your answer say how I can achieve an implement this table. I currently have a site so could I host a SQLite database. If so please link to a tutorial/guide. Also if anyone has found one: a tutorial to implement this database in Xcode.

Just looking for the best route to go but I'm not looking to pay for something like Kumlos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make databse into your server and one sqlite in you iOS application. Then you can synchronize them. Make one php script that retrive information from database and the convert it to JSON. From you app download this JSON parse it and then save it to the db. This is approach that I use.

Update:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Comment: Have any links that could help?

Comment: Ok thanks but what if I wanted to put my data in a nsarray like [listOfItems addobject:@"Item1"]

Comment: What do you want to pot in an array?

Comment: I have products and their descriptions and prices. I plan on feeding the array to a table